# Prove that there exists a one-color $K_3$ in a $K_{17}$ which is colored with three colors

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Assume that we have a $K_{17}$ and we color every edge of it with 3 colors ( Like Red, Blue & green ).

Prove that for every coloring of $K_{17}$ with 3 colors, After coloring, We have a one-color $K_3$.

Note 1:
What i tried is that i picked and vertex like $v$ and i fixed it.
 Then I said this vertex is connected to $16$ other vertices ($v_1,\cdots,v_{16})$.
By the pigeonhole principle we know that there exists a color that at least 6 of the edges between $v$ and $v_i$'s.
Without loss of generality, We say that color is blue and that 6 vertices are $(v_1,\cdots,v_6)$.
Now we see the edges between $v_i$'s. If there exists a blue edges between these vertices, We are done ! 
What i'm stuck on is what to do if there is no blue edge between $v_i$'s.

Note 2: Don't use ramsey numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there's no blue edge between $v_i$'s then you've got a $K_6$ whose edges are colored with two colors. Have you seen anything about two-colored $K_6$'s? If you have, this is a good place to use it. If you haven't attack it the same way you did the $K_{17}$ problem: Pick one of those six vertices and look at the $5$ edges joining it to the others . . .

Comment: @bof Thank you dude :) I know that ! What a good place to use it ! I'll delete my question :)

Comment: @bof i'm not sure ... should i delete the question anyway ?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade it's not a duplicate so there is no need to delete it, it might be helpful for other people in the future :)

Comment: @H.Potter ok :)

Comment: It would be good if either you or @bof would post the answer as an answer so that you can accept it so the question doesn't remain unanswered.